# Adding Script to separate .js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm have added below script on the .aspx page header tags and it works perfectly with out any issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('#InfoPage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
           $("#apdf").click(function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               var serviceURL = "Default.aspx/GeneratePDF";

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: serviceURL,
                   data: param = "", // parameter
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: successFunc,
                   error: errorFunc
               });

               function successFunc(data) {

                   alert('sucess');
               }

               function errorFunc() {
                   alert('error');
               }

           });
       });
   </script>
```

later i thought to clean up my code and added the above script to a separate .js file and added the link to the page header tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PDFScript.js"/>
```

Then suddenly it stopped working web page did not render any thing at all even the static content were not shown. Any specific reason for this to happen?

I also tried below.

```
<div data-role="page" id="InfoPage">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="PDFScript.js"/>
</div>
```

Comment: did you remove the <script type="text/javascript"> tag in the external file?

Comment: did your javascript code came after the <div data-role="page" id="InfoPage"> div? else the javascript code will now be executed before so #InfoPage wont yet exist. you can use $(document).ready(function(){ [code here] } to be sure your code get executed afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the `<script type="text/javascript" src="PDFScript.js"/>` before the `</body>` tag. Else make sure to import it after jQuery, jQuery Mobile js libraries.

If you are using jQuery 1.9.x then `live` wont' work for you. You need to use `.on()` method.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#InfoPage', function(){
   // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: are you sure you are not importing `PDFScript.js` before jquery, jquery Mobile, your plugins?

Comment: Yes I did import after the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$('#InfoPage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
```

to this:

```
$(document).live('pageshow', '#InfoPage' ,function (event) {
```

To understand this better read this article (it is not mine) : http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events and look for the chapter: **Event delegation**